# Wordpress Loop integrated with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So this is kind of hard to explain in text, I have attached an image to go with it so it should make a bit more sense!

Basically, I want to show recent posts in a line. They will be displayed via the_post_thumbnail.

When you click on a thumbnail, above it a div will become unhidden and will slide the content down to reveal information about the thumbnail clicked. If you click the next thumbnail, the current div will slide back up and hide, and then another hidden div will slide down and show the information for the next thumbnail.

http://lifestyletrader.com/jqueryidea.jpg

I really have no idea how to go about doing this, so any help would be greatly appreciated with upvotes :D!

Comment: So which part are you asking for help with? :) The Wordpress is loop is very versatile and pretty manageable. Is there any particular part that's giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use some of the jquery plugins for creating galleries, like [AD Gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/2009/07/ad-gallery-a-jquery-gallery-plugin/)?

Hopefully It will need only some tweak to adjust it to your needs.

See this [AD Gallery example](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/) and tell me if something like this is what you need.

Comment: Okey, I will take a look to your examples and see how you can adapt the jquery plugin for accomplish that.

Comment: Okay, so I have written the WP-loop to display the content, and put in a little jquery to make it look a tad fancy.

Here is a working version roughly based off the example I found - http://mathewhood.com/sitefiles/

Here is my HTML and the Loop - http://jsfiddle.net/dFdyP/

Answer (score 1):

In the example you posted it seems that the HTML for all the posts is built on a secondary page ([found here](http://themes.premiumpixels.com/garnish/wp-content/themes/garnish/includes/home-magicdoor.php)) which is included in the main collapsible div. That div has its height set to 0 and whenever you click on a thumbnail from below:

1. The internal content is moved to the correct position (probably based on an id retrieved from the clicked thumbnail)
2. The div is expanded using something like jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

If it's already expanded; it's collapsed using animate, the content is moved to the new position, then it is re-expanded.

Now to take this back to the WordPress loop I suppose you could do one of two things:

1. Use the loop to build a similar structure where you load all posts
   and build large "focus" blocks for them and hide them (like this
   example) then show the relevant one once its thumbnail is clicked
2. Use the loop to build the thumbnails, and set the wordpress post id
   as each thumbnail's id, then asynchronously reload the large section
   of the page using ajax. This is probably harder, but more efficient,
   and I'm not exactly sure how to do it. :)

Comment: D: this just got a lot harder than I expected haha :(!

I will have a read over what you posted and try and nut it out, but it really is looking to be harder than I expected D:

Comment: The first option should be pretty easy if you're familiar with the WP loop and if you have a relatively small set of posts you want to feature. If you can build the HTML using the loop, it's simply a matter of a couple of basic jQuery animations.

Comment: I might have a play and try and get some sample code going, then if I am struggling post here and get you to have a look at it if you wouldn't mind :)?

Comment: Sure if I get the notification in time and can help. :) Please remember to accept or at least up vote my answer if it helps.

Comment: Okay, so I have written the WP-loop to display the content, and put in a little jquery to make it look a tad fancy. 

Here is a working version roughly based off the example I found - mathewhood.com/sitefiles

Here is my HTML and the Loop - jsfiddle.net/dFdyP

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the thumbnails (the page just refreshes).

Comment: @MathewHood let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2507/discussion-between-mjisrawi-and-mathew-hood)

Comment: Something is happening. Basically when you click the thumbnail, it is taking you to the post but using the same page template as the homepage. I haven't written a specific single page post template as I want the posts to be displayed on the homepage using that jquery etc :).

I think if I can call <?php the_content();?> into the jquery for the sliding animate thing then it will show the page content. I am just not sure how to structure the jquery.